# How to query TFS Work Items to count how many times each one had the state "Resolved"?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I need to know how many times a Work Item had the state `Resolved`.

Is it possible using the `Work > Queries` or some Widget in `Home > Overview` tabs in TFS 2015 or VSO/VSTS?

Is it possible using TFS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be achieved by Query, but you can get the information via [TFS .NET Client Library API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet) or [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview).

For .NET Client Library API, you need to get the workitem first and then check every revision in the workitem to count the revisions with "Resolved State".

For Rest API, you can get all the revisions of the workitem by following this page: [Get a list of work items revisions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/revisions#get-a-list-of-work-items-revisions) and then check how many times the workitem state was "Resolved".

Add a simple code sample for .NET Client Library API:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

namespace CountState
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com";
            string state = "Resolved";
            int workitemid = 111;
            int statecount = 0;
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(url));
            WorkItemStore wis = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            WorkItem wi = wis.GetWorkItem(workitemid);
            foreach (Revision rev in wi.Revisions)
            {
                if (rev.Fields["State"].Value.ToString() == state)
                {
                    statecount = statecount + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```